# Java / Abstract Class

Tags: java

I have an abstract class with one abstract method and I want to implement the method in 3 different classes but 2 of this 3 classes have the same implementation for the method as below code, what can I do to have one implementation for both classes ?
NOTE: I cannot represent C & D as a one class!!

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract void method();
}

class B extends A
{
    void method(){print "Hello";}
}

class C extends A
{
    void method(){print "Bye";}
}

class D extends A
{
    void method(){print "Bye";}
}
```

Comment: Just add the method in `A`, and override it in `B`, no need to implement anything in `C` and `D` as they already inherit it.

Comment: make a class CD and inherit C and D from it

Comment: `D extends C`? Or duplicate the code as you just did. Or `Bye extends A`, `C extends Bye`, `D extends Bye` with `Bye` implementing the method.

Comment: No, Abubakkar has it right.  Put the default implementation in the abstract class and only have classes that want something else override it.

Comment: @RaduIonescu did not even have time to write it myself

Comment: Or, add it as a protected static method in A, so that implementations can just reference it easily (`void method() { A.standardMethod(); }`). That way implementers still have to think about which implementation they want, but can easily get it.

Comment: @luk2302 but that way `D` would be a `C` which it wouldn´t be in the original scenario, at least for the `D extends C` scenario

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy that is why I included two "or".

Comment: Thank you but there's a problem now if I have a class called F and implements the method like class B !! do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one step in between. Make an abstract Class implementing the method and derive from it for C and D

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract void method();
}

abstract class CD extends A {
    void method(){print "Bye";}
}

class B extends A {
    void method(){print "Hello";}
}

class C extends CD { }

class D extends CD { }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could eliminate some complexity here and implement the "Bye" method directly in base class A, and override it with the "Hello" method in the derived class B:

```
class A { void method() { print "Bye"; } }

class B extends A { void method() { print "Hello"; } }
```

If A must remain abstract then you can create an intermediate class that contains the behaviour that classes C and D require, and then C and simply extend that without overriding any methods:

```
abstract class A { abstract void method(); }

abstract class CD extends A { void method() { print "Bye"; } }

class B extends A { void method() { print "Hello"; } }

class C extends CD { }

class D extends CD { }
```

There are other options, such as extracting the common behaviour to new classes and reusing them through composition rather than inheritance - if your classes are sufficiently complex then this arguably makes it simpler to encapsulate single responsibilities and facilitate testing.

Comment: Thank you but there's a problem now if I have a class called F and implements the method like class B !! do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Make class F extend class B?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you there - you said that F would have the same method as B, so it should extend B. If F already extends A, then you have no choice but to override it again in F. In terms of code reuse, in this case you can extract the message code into a Bye class and a Hello class (potentially with a common interface), and call those as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Put the default behavior in A.

```
abstract class A {
    public void method() {print "Bye";}
}

class B extends A {
    void method(){print "Hello";}
}

class C extends A {
    // uses the parent method
}

class D extends A {
    // uses the parent method
}
```

Comment: Please remove *abstract* from *method* in class A.

Comment: Thanks, missed it.

Comment: Thank you but there's a problem now if I have a class called F and implements the method like class B !! do you have a solution for that?

Comment: This example is getting out of hand.  Have class F extend B; it'll get the grandparen's behavior for method until it overrides it.